# Can I use if statements in a stored procedure to insert values into a table?

Tags: oracle, if-statement, stored-procedures, plsql

I am trying to write a stored procedure that selects indiv_ids and transaction_ids and inserts these into a table on my schema. In doing so, I want to pass in variables and have the stored procedure use if statements to select the indiv_ids and transaction_ids from different tables depending on the information passed in. I've tried a few variations and can't get the procedure to work without an error. Thanks!

```
 create or replace procedure myproc (name_type in varchar2, dept in number)
 is begin 
 if name_type='promo' then insert into mytable(indiv_id,transaction_id)
 ---sql here; 
 commit;
 elsif name_type='deal' then insert into mytable(indiv_id, transaction_id)
 ---sql here;
 commit;
 end if;
 end;


 errors: Error(8,10): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored, 
         Error(16,31): PL/SQL:  ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Comment: First if statement is missing end if

Comment: @NaughtyNinja thanks for the comment. I've tried ding separate if statements and it doesn't change anything. With the current syntax I am getting SQL statement ignored and table or view does not exist errors. Noth still occur if I break up the if statements

Comment: You should add the error stack you get to the question. If you get the error in your comment then either `mytable` or one of the tables you query doesn't exist; or you don't have access to it from a procedure. Do you own all of the tables involved, or are some in other schemas (accessed through synonyms or by setting `current_schema` or with schema-qualified names)?

Comment: @AlexPoole  Error(28,12): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored Error(36,31): PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist. The errors I am getting. I first thought it was about permissions, but I created a simple test procedure using the tables I don't own and was indeed able to create the procedure.

Comment: Please add the error stack *to the question*. Maybe you have just misspelled a table name then. You check permissions with another procedure, not an anonymous block? We can't see your schema or privileges or queries, so we can't narrow it down for you. It's nothing to do with the `if` construct though.

Comment: Thanks @AlexPoole I added the errors in. I can't put the pull query in because of my company, though I have double checked for spelling errors. It's good to know the if statements are done correctly. I did try running another procedure from the tables in question and it works. So I am stumped as to why it won't run.

Comment: Can you run the insert query standalone in SQL\*Plus as the same user? If so does it still work if you do `set role none` first?

Answer (score 0):

Note that `name_type` variable is declared as `NUMBER`, but in the procedure body it is compared with strings:

```
if name_type='promo' then
```

This is not the cause of ORA-00942 error, but anyway it makes your procedure not working correctly.

Comment: My apologies, it is varchar2 in my current query.